# how to do i fix this problem, node:internal/process/promises:279 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
 if(file.type.includes('image')) {
        // means user upload an image
        fetch('/s3url').then(res => res.json())
            .then(url => {
                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }),
                    body: file
                }).then(res => {
                    imageUrl = url.split("?")[0];
                    imgPath[index] = imageUrl;
                    let label = document.querySelector(`label[for=${fileupload.id}]
                `);
                    label.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
                    let productImg = document.querySelector('.product-image');
                    productImg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
                })
            })
    } else{
        showAlert('upload image only')
    }

})
})
```

When trying to upload pictures to my the ecom website, to my amazon bucket i get
`node:internal/process/promises:279 triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);`
I have looked over my code and done so much research and still cannot find a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the aws-sdk? It's hard to tell from the question, but generally, to upload to bucket in node.js, you'd need to get the file as a blob then use the sdk to upload it. You'd also need the IAM key for permission to upload as well.

So check first, if you are trying to upload to it as a blob not a url to the image and that you are using the sdk to upload to it not http request,